# error /bin/sh: 1: sourcekitten: not found on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, swift, bash, ubuntu

I'm using SourceKitten to get code completions for swift. I'm trying to invoke the command through the following code:

```
var str = 'sourcekitten complete --text "' + code + '"';       
const proc = exec(str, function(err, stdout, stderr) {         
    if (err || stderr) {           
        console.log('error', stderr);           
        return resolve([]);         
    } 
    try {           
        return resolve(JSON.parse(stdout));         
    } catch (error) {           
        console.log('error', error);           
        return resolve([]);         
    }
});
```

I am getting the following error: `error /bin/sh: 1: sourcekitten: not found`. I have downloaded sourcekitten from `https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten` and have done `swift build` too. Even using 
    `var str = 'SourceKitten/Source/sourcekitten complete --text "' + code + '"';`  gives the same error.

Comment: Post the o/p of `which sourcekitten`?

Comment: `which sourcekitten` gives empty output.

Comment: can you provide the full path to `sourcekitten` binary?

Comment: `~/SourceKitten/.build/debug/sourcekitten`

Comment: is your script located in the home directory?

Comment: It is located at `~/swift`

Comment: `var str = '../sourcekitten complete --text "' + code + '"';` should likely solve your problem Note the `../` added in the beginning.

Comment: It still gives me the same error. Also, if I try `SourceKitten/.build/debug/sourcekitten complete` from the terminal, it gives ```<unknown>:0: error: unable to load standard library for target 'x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
[]```